# backbone.js model.set is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to use backbone.js model.set property.  The second alert function should fire off after todo1.set is being implemented.  However it is not.
Here is the jsfiddle link: **http://jsfiddle.net/SGEkn/**

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            title: "Harsh",
            completed: false
        }, 
        initialize: function() {
            console.log('This model has been initialized.')
        }
    });

var todo2 = new Todo({
    title: 'Set through instantiation.',
    completed: true
});
console.log('Todo title: ' + todo2.get('title'));
console.log('Todo completed ' + todo2.get('completed'));

alert("ok");

todo2.set("title", 'Title set');

alert("ok");

console.log(todo2.get('title'));
todo.set("completed", false);

console.log('completed: ' + todo2.get('completed'));
```

Comment: Why are you using Backbone 0.3.3?

Comment: my mistake, thats why i'm having lots of other issues as well with it. thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be passing an object and not the arguments individually.

```
todo2.set({"title":'Title set'});
```

Comment: `todo2.set('title', 'Title set')` is fine if you're using a non-ancient version of Backbone.

Comment: ehh, i'm usingreally old version, thats why.  now makes sense

Comment: Side note: I would be more consistent in the use of single quotes or double quotes. Try not to mix them unless necessary.